# Safari Flexbox cutting off content

Tags: html, css, safari

I have 3 rows, **header**, **content** and **footer**. It renders as expected in Chrome, but cuts off the bottom in Safari. What am I doing wrong?

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BF9Zl.png)

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  height: 100%;
}

.content {
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div className="wrapper">
  <div className="header">I am a header</div>
  <div className="content">I am some content</div>
  <div className="footer">
    <ul>
      <li>Hi</li>
      <li>Hi</li>
      <li>Hi</li>
      <li>Hi</li>
      <li>Hi</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```